# Insert delay in sqlite database using Retrofit

Tags: android

I have used Retrofit in my app for API calls. In my app, there is an requirement to call 4 API calls in background and 
insert corresponding values in sqlite database. Particularly in one API call, there is a need to 
insert values in three table with in single for loop.
At that time, the device hanged because of suspending all threads. Please anyone help, how to rectify this.

Comment: Move the db operation to a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

For this issue, you can use Async task to insert the data to db in side retrofit success block. Even though retrofit handle this part in background it handle by using thread.

In android developer doc it stated that thread can be suspended by system during configuration change. So while inserting the data the thread may suspended and makes your app to hang and wont executing any task.

Ref: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Comment: Yes, this helps me lot. Thanks.